# I want Fedora 15 to automount media with non-root permissions

Tags: linux, fedora, automount, fedora-15

I'm Ubuntu ex-fan (because of gnome-shell).

On Ubuntu, there was this very sane feature (for laptop/desktop user): when you insert a thumbdrive or external usb media, the system mounts the media and sets all the correct permissions for the current non-root logged in user.

What do I have to change/edit/configure to make Fedora 15 behave like this?

Comment: GNOME is _supposed to_ automount media, provided you have `gnome-settings-daemon` running (GNOME 3; or `nautilus` in GNOME 2). Check the process list.

Comment: There was nothing wrong about the system. The problem was that my external USB disk was formatted as EXT3 and all the files had the wrong permissions. ´´chmod -R´´ fixed it.

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and mark the title as "[SOLVED]" so we know that you solved your issue.

Comment: Your question implied that Fedora didn't mount the devices at all, not that it merely left "incorrect" permissions.

Comment: @grawity My external drive had permissions for user 1001 (ubuntu), On Fedora, the user # was 500 (Don't know why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong about the system. The problem was that my external USB disk was formatted as EXT3 and all the files had the wrong permissions. ´´chmod -R´´ fixed it.